# How to keep my circle div from moving

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Inside this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kapena/pen/LVdYQa?editors=110)
each of the circles need to transition into a new configuration at `800px`. The configuration I'm looking for is to have `circle1` and `circle2` still centered in the page and have `circle3` underneath circles 1 and 2. For clarity the image bellow show's how I want the circles to end up.

[image: Circles in correct postion]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle1">
    <a id="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
  </div>

  <div class="circle2">
    <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="circle3">
      <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the screen shot I'm was able to transition `circle1` and `circle2` into moving slightly to the left while also moving `circle3` underneath `circle1` and `circle2` by telling `circle3` to move `left: -150px`.

However `circle3` does **not** want to stay in his position when he is moved. So if I slide him down then we will obviously keep sliding to the bottom left. No matter where I move `circle3` he keeps on moving when I move the view port to smaller size.

Here is my media query that is telling the circles to move when at `800px`:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .circles {
    width: 80%;
  }

  .circle1, circle2 {
    left: 20%;
  }

  .circle3 {
    left: -150px;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking this has something to moving `circle3` to `left: -150px`.

How do I keep the `circle3` from continuing to move while also keeping it centered between `circle1` and `circle2`?

Comment: Can we see some html?

Comment: Sure..I'm begging to think that what I want to achieve here is quite hard to do with flex box as that's what I am using to layout the css.

Comment: Did you see my answer? Could you comment it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my solution (compiled SCSS to CSS for code snippet, see original on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sergdenisov/pen/GJdwqP?editors=110)):

```css
.circles {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
}

.circle1, .circle2, .circle3 {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    height: 0;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: magenta;
    left: 0;
    transition: margin-top 0.5s linear, left 0.5s linear;
}

.circle1 #projects, .circle2 #projects, .circle3 #projects, .circle2 #about, .circle3 #contact {
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: -0.5em;
    padding-top: 50%;
    color: #fff;
}

.circle2 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.circle3 {
    background-color: gold;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .circle1, .circle2, .circle3, .circle2 {
        left: 15%;
    }

    .circle3 {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 28.5%;
        left: -35.11%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
    <div class="circle1">
        <a id="projects" href="#">Projects</a>
    </div>

    <div class="circle2">
        <a id="about" href="#">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="circle3">
        <a id="contact" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You use relative values to set element's height (it's `padding-bottom: 30%` in your case), but absolute value to top position of `.circle3` (`top: 90px`). When you're resizing viewport, height of all circles are changing, but `.circle3` continues to have fixed position.

I changed `top: 90px` to `margin-top: 28.5%` and it seems OK. Also removed some unnecessary code.

P.S. Maybe I didn't understand your question but I saw only this problem.

Comment: Very good answer @Sergey I see what happens by changing out `top:90px` to `margin-top:28.5%` However I solved the issue before I saw your answer. I also changed up the configuration of the circles to have the **projects** circle on top and the other two bellow. Anyway's to fix my issue I was able to use `left:-18%` when adjusting the circles to a media query at `800`px . Feel free go check out my **entirely new solution on the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kapena/bb2zr7vk/2/) **Feedback will be  greatly appreciated **Sorry for taking a while to get back to you**

Answer (score 0):

I think that `circle3` looks like he is moving but he actually is not..What's happening is that I moved him out of his original position in the first place therefore `circle3` **only** knows where he should be based on where I told him to go.

Since I told `circle3` to move `left:-150px;` he has gone there and will stay there even as I make the view port smaller. What is changing is the view port not `circle3` has he stays in his position but dose not adjust to the position of the view port as I make it smaller.

I believe this is why `circle3` will not stay centered between the two circles as he dose not know how to adjust at this moment.